# Mongo - reference other schema by value that isnt ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So theoretically, let's say I have a `Posts` schema and want want to link the User that created it in the schema. Traditionally I would put in the schema

```
        posted_by: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        }
```

Lets say the user had a field called "user_serial_no", is there a way I can reference the User from the Post using this other field (which will be unique) rather than the ObjectId?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `aggregate.lookup()`

More info : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-lookup

```
const result = await Posts.aggregate([
        {
            '$lookup': {
                'from': User.collection.name,
                'localField': 'posted_by',
                'foreignField': 'user_serial_no',
                'as': 'postByUser' // <= Mongoose will create a new field as a result for you 
            }
        },
        /*Other options like $projections & $unwind if needed*/
    ])
```